# Background attachment fixed causing lags on webpage scroll

Tags: html, css

I have an issue on my landing page, where my background picture which is set to has a following styles:

```
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-image: url('../images/image.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

I've investigated, and found out that background-attachment property causes lags on scrolling. If I delete background-attachment property, scrolling is smooth.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Best way is to get rid of fixed background. If you really want to do it let's try having fixed width body height, normal background, then in your main container appy overflow-y: scroll

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you cannot simply remove the property of `background-attachment`?